# Calculated Field in Custom CRM 4.0 Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

The onload event is firing and I am not getting any erroors, but the calculated field is not refreshing?
It should be doing the calculation from the function FWeightedValue().

Here is the code, any help would be appreciated.

```
frmOnLoad();
    onLoad = false;

}
catch(e)
{ alert(e.message); }
}//End of if condition
}//End of function



/* Declare Variables */
var onLoad = true;
var sGlobalVar = '';


function frmOnLoad()
{   ResizeScreen();
    AddLogoToFormTitle(160, "/CRM4Legal/_imgs/reznick_small.gif");

    fldMerge('name');
    fldMerge('customerid');
    fldMerge('rg_officeid');

    fldStatus();
    fldGSMC();

    FWeightedValue();

    frmTabs();
    frmNav();
    frmIFrames();

    if ($("rg_gsmc"  ) != null) $("rg_gsmc" ).onclick = fldGSMC;

}

function FWeightedValue()
{   with ( crmForm.all )

    var EstRev        = crmForm.getAttribute("estimatedvalue").getValue();
    var RiskWeight  = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("cpdc_riskweight").getValue();
    var RiskPercent = RiskWeight / 100;
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("cpdc_riskweightedvalue").setValue(RiskWeightValue);
sectionDisplay( true, cpdc_riskweightedvalue);

}


FWeightedValue.NullCheck = function (value) 
        {
            if (value == null) {
                return 0.0;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }

}

function fldStatus()
{   with ( crmForm.all )
    {   if ( statuscode.SelectedText == 'Won' || statuscode.SelectedText == 'Lost' )
        {   crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("rg_winlossreason", 1);
            sectionDisplay( false, rg_winlossreason );
        }
        else
        {   crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("rg_winlossreason", 0);
            rg_winlossreason.DataValue = null;
            sectionDisplay( true, rg_winlossreason );
        }
    }
}

function fldGSMC()
{   with ( crmForm.all )
    {   sectionDisplay( !rg_gsmc.DataValue, rg_contractnumber );
        crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("rg_contracttype", ( rg_gsmc.DataValue ? 1 : 0 ));
    }
}

function fldMerge(fld)
{   if ( fld == null ) { return; }

    var cell = $(fld + '_d');
    if ( cell == null ) { return; }

    var row = cell.parentNode;
    if ( row == null ) { return; }

    cell.colSpan = 3;
    row.removeChild(cell.nextSibling);
    row.removeChild(cell.nextSibling);

}

function frmTabs()
{   tab('Hidden', 'hidden');
}

function frmNav()
{   navHide ('nav_rg_opportunity_rg_opportunitypracticearea');
    navHide ('nav_rg_opportunity_rg_opportunityservicearea');
    navHide ('nav_rg_opportunity_rg_engagementteam');
    navHide ('nav_rg_opportunity_rg_opportunityteam');

    navHide ('navProducts');
    navHide ('navQuotes');
    navHide ('navOrders');
    navHide ('navInvoices');
    navHide ('navComp');
    navHide ('_NA_SFA');}

function frmIFrames()
{   /* Engagement Team */
    var n2nPA = new N2NViewer('IFRAME_EngagementTeam');  
    /* Set the role order - use iedevtoolber for exact parameters */   
    n2nPA.RoleOrder = 1;  
    /* assing the relationship name (without the "area" word) */   
    n2nPA.TabsetId  = "rg_opportunity_rg_engagementteam";  
    n2nPA.Load();  

    /* Opportunity Team */
    var n2nPA = new N2NViewer('IFRAME_OpportunityTeam');  
    n2nPA.RoleOrder = 1;  
    n2nPA.TabsetId  = "rg_opportunity_rg_opportunityteam";  
    n2nPA.Load();  

    /* Practice Areas */
    var n2nPA = new N2NViewer('IFRAME_PracticeAreas');  
    n2nPA.RoleOrder = 1;  
    n2nPA.TabsetId  = "rg_opportunity_rg_opportunitypracticearea";  
    n2nPA.Load();  

    /* Service Areas */
    var n2nService = new N2NViewer('IFRAME_Services');  
    n2nService.RoleOrder = 1;  
    n2nService.TabsetId  = "rg_opportunity_rg_opportunityservicearea";  
    n2nService.Load();  
}

function $(name)
{   return document.getElementById(name);
}

function navHide (name)
{   if ($(name) != null) { $(name).style.display = "none"; }
}

function tab ( tabName, tabVisibility )
{   tabVisibility = ( tabVisibility == "visible" ? "" : "none" );

    var _tabs = crmForm.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < _tabs.length; i++) 
    {   var _tab = _tabs[i]; 
        if ( _tab.innerText == tabName ) 
        {   _tab.style.display = tabVisibility;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function sectionDisplay(vis, sec) 
{   sec.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = ((vis) ? 'none' : 'block');
}

function ResizeScreen() 
{   var aH = screen.availHeight;
    var aW = screen.availWidth;
    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;

    if ( aW >= 1124 && aH >= 800) 
    {   var aH = (aH > 800 ? 800 : 768);
        var aW = 1124;
        var top = (screen.availHeight - aH) / 2;
        var left = (screen.availWidth - aW) / 2;
    }
//  aH = (crmForm.FormType == frmType.Create ? 295 : aH);
    window.moveTo(left, top);
    window.resizeTo(aW, aH);
}

function N2NViewer(iframeId)  
{   if (!document.all[iframeId])  
    {   alert(iframeId + " is missing!");  
        return;  
    }

    var viewer = this;  
    var _locAssocObj = null;  

    viewer.IFRAME = document.all[iframeId];  
    viewer.RoleOrder;  
    viewer.TabsetId;  

    viewer.Load = function()  
    {   if (crmForm.ObjectId != null)
        {   /* Construct a valid N2N IFRAME url */  
            viewer.IFRAME.src = "areas.aspx?oId=" + crmForm.ObjectId + "&oType=" + crmForm.ObjectTypeCode + "&security=" + crmFormSubmit.crmFormSubmitSecurity.value + "&roleOrd=" + viewer.RoleOrder +  "&tabSet=" + viewer.TabsetId;  
            viewer.IFRAME.onreadystatechange = viewer.StateChanged;  
        }
        else
        {   viewer.IFRAME.src = "about:blank";  
        }
    }

    viewer.StateChanged = function()  
    {   if (viewer.IFRAME.readyState != 'complete')  
        {   return;  
        }

        var iframeDoc = viewer.IFRAME.contentWindow.document;  

        /* Reomve scrolling space */  
        iframeDoc.body.scroll = "no";  
        /* Remove crmGrid Default padding */  
        iframeDoc.body.childNodes[0].rows[0].cells[0].style.padding = 0;  

        /* Save MS locAssocObj */  
        _locAssocObj = locAssocObj;  
        /* Override MS locAssocObj */  
        locAssocObj = viewer.locAssocObj;  
    }  

    viewer.locAssocObj = function(iType , sSubType, sAssociationName, iRoleOrdinal)  
    {   /* Open the Dialog */  
        _locAssocObj(iType , sSubType, sAssociationName, iRoleOrdinal);  
        /* Refresh only if our iframe contains the correnct tabset name */  
        if (sAssociationName == viewer.TabsetId)  
        {   viewer.IFRAME.contentWindow.document.all.crmGrid.Refresh();   
        }
    }  
}   


function AddLogoToFormTitle(logoWidth, logoUrl) 
{   var formTitleTable = null;
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

    for(var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++)
    {   var className = tables[i].className;
        if (className && className.indexOf("ms-crm-Form-Title") == 0) 
        {   formTitleTable = tables[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (formTitleTable) 
    {   var newCell = formTitleTable.rows[0].insertCell(2);
        newCell.width = logoWidth;
        newCell.vAlign = "middle";
        newCell.innerHTML = '<img src="'+logoUrl+'" border="0" align="right" />';
    }
}



function UnUsed()
{
  if(false)
  {
    try
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed CRM 4.0 and CRM 2011 SDKs. No wonder nothing is working!
Below is what should be written if your target platform is CRM 4.0

```
function FWeightedValue()
{    
    var EstRev      = crmForm.estimatedvalue.DataValue;
    var RiskWeight  = crmForm.cpdc_riskweight.DataValue;
    var RiskPercent = RiskWeight / 100;
    crmForm.cpdc_riskweightedvalue.DataValue = RiskWeightValue;
    // second parameter is sec ??? or field 
    sectionDisplay( true, crmForm.cpdc_riskweightedvalue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Force Submit?

```
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).setSubmitMode("always");
```